# django makemigrations --check with output?

Tags: django

I'm trying to combine two behaviours of the makemigrations command in my CI:

- `makemigrations --check` will return non-zero when a migration file needs to be generated
- `makemigrations --dry-run` will print details about the ungenerated migration
- `makemigrations --check --dry-run` behaves as `makemigrations --check` (since Django 4.2).

My CI script needs to fail if there are ungenerated migrations and it would be helpful if it also described the missing migrations.

Is there a cleaner way to do this besides some `bash` tricks involving both options?

Comment: Run `--check`, and if it is nonzero, then run `--dry-run` as a second step.

Comment: @JohnGordon also we need to return the status code from the first step. We're doing it the other way around for now, it saves an `if`.  But I was just wondering if there was an option we were missing.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an unfortunate regression for the use case of `--check --dry-run` which I too was using.

I don't think there's a way to do it without running `makemigrations` twice now. In case anyone just wants a quick solution, the "bash tricks" would be something like:

```bash
./manage.py makemigrations --no-input --dry-run && ./manage.py makemigrations --check
```

But I prefer to use `tox` to run these things and in `tox.ini` you can simply have two commands, e.g.:

```ini
[testenv]
commands =
         python manage.py makemigrations --no-input --dry-run
         python manage.py makemigrations --check
```